# Edit button for each DataTable row, can't pass data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables-1.10

I have a DataTable called Branches which has three columns: Name, Code and Email (along with an ID column hidden to users). It originally has an Edit button on top, and only after clicking on a row can the user click on the button to open a dialog box with the fields populated and edit them. Now however I need to change it so that each row has its own Edit button, therefore removing the need to click on the row first.

So now I have an Edit button for each row in a DataTable, but I can't pass the data for that particular row besides the Index number. The relevant blocks of code are below (unless I missed something, please tell me if I have):

```
var txtName2 = $("#txtName2"); //For Update
var txtCode2 = $("#txtCode2");
var txtEmail2 = $("#txtEmail2");
var dialog;
var tblBranch = $("#tblBranches");
var branchList;
var selectedIndex;

branchList = response.branches;
var data = { "aaData": [] };

    $.each(response.branches, function (i, item) {
        data.aaData.push({
            "id": item.id,
            "name": item.name,
            "code": item.code,
            "email": item.email,
            "action": "<button> class='btnUpdate' type='button' onClick='testUpdateButton(" + i + ")'</button>"
        });
    });

function testUpdateButton(index, name, code, email) {
    //alert(index);
    selectedIndex = tblBranch.row(this).index();
    var selectedName = tblBranch.row(index).name;
    var selectedCode = tblBranch.row(index).code;
    var selectedEmail = tblBranch.row(index).email;
    //alert(name);
    onBtnUpdateClicked(index, name, code, email);
    }

function onBtnUpdateClicked(index, name, code, email) {
    if (branchList != null && branchList.length > 0) {
        var selectedItem = branchList[selectedIndex];
        txtName2.val(selectedItem.name);
        txtCode2.val(selectedItem.code);
        txtEmail2.val(selectedItem.email);
        dialog = $("#dialog-form-update").dialog("open");
        }
    }
```

When I only pass in the index number 'i' at the button and not the name, code or email, the alert(index) under testUpdateButton displays the correct index number of the selected row, therefore confirming it can get the index number, but not the other three columns (the alert(name) displays nothing).

So I've tried passing all four fields at the button like such:

```
"action": "<button> class='btnUpdate' type='button' onClick='testUpdateButton(" + i + ", " + item.name + ", " + item.code + ", " + item.email + ")'</button>"
```

but it only gives me an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" when I inspect the page in Chrome. I can't see where the missing bracket should be.

Basically, I can obtain the index number but cannot use it to get the corresponding name, code and email.

For reference, here is the function that's the closest thing to a solution I had earlier - this would pass all the row data and load the Editing dialog box with the input fields populated whenever I clicked anywhere on the row itself. It was modified from the previous "Click on row first" version, though I merely added the onBtnUpdateClicked function. Not ideal, but at least it did what it should.

```
$("#tblBranches tbody").on('click', 'tr', function () {
    selectedIndex = tblBranch.row(this).index();
    onBtnUpdateClicked();
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are able to get the index of row, you can use this to get other values. Try something like this

```
function testUpdateButton(index){
            //alert(index);
        selectedIndex = index;
        var name=$("table tr").eq(index).children('td').eq(1).text();
        var email=$("table tr").eq(index).children('td').eq(2).text();
        alert(name);
        alert(email);
        onBtnUpdateClicked(index, name, email);
}
```

A woorking fiddle to get these values is https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/atpgdofh/19/. This is not a complete solution, but yes this will help you to get other values, which you can pass in your onBtnUpdateClicked function. You have to change the functions as per your table structure and in your onBtnUpdateClicked use these values as below-

```
function onBtnUpdateClicked(index, name, email) {
    if (branchList != null && branchList.length > 0) {
        var selectedItem = branchList[index];
        txtName2.val(name);
        txtEmail2.val(email);
        dialog = $("#dialog-form-update").dialog("open");
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I have used and changed your code accordingly, though I still have an issue. The dialog box now appears, but for some reason it only gets data on the first row, and the data somehow is from the ninth row. No data is taken for any other rows. I have followed your Fiddle code, but I think there's something wrong in my testUpdateButton function. It's the same as yours except for an extra line to get the Code, and the eq numbers are 0 to 2.

Comment: @Alycus can you show me the updated code with your datatable structure?

Comment: @Alycus two problems are there..1- Syntax error (extra } at the end of function), 2-you are using $("#tblBranches tr") for traversing tr, this will include your <tr> within the <thead>. I have updated my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/atpgdofh/20/ and its working

Comment: Hello, thanks for your correction. I've got it working now, but I had to add the Index Number column to the datatable, as it's supposed to hidden. Is it possible for it to still work while keeping the Index Number column hidden? Thanks again for helping me make progress.

Comment: @Alycus There is no need to add Index column, just pass the index number as a parameter to your testUpdateButton function. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shoaibakhter/atpgdofh/22/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109120/discussion-between-alycus-and-shoaib-akhter).